# How do I assign a JBOD disk to RAID 1 in AMD RAIDXpert?

Tags: raid

On motherboards equipped with AMD RAIDXpert, when a RAID 1 configuration fails swapping out the failed drive allowed the computer to boot again, but the new drive was assigned to a singular JBOD configuration instead of being assigned back to the RAID that failed. How do I resolve this issue so that the new drive is part of the RAID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the [manual](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/AMD_RAIDXpert_User_v2.1.pdf) is a bit unclear about the correct procedure, resolving this issue is not too difficult. Assuming that AMD RAIDXpert is already installed on your system:

1. Login to the control panel which should be at `http://localhost:25902/`
2. Click on "Logical Drive View"
3. Click on the "Delete" tab
4. Find the disk that you just installed, it should be listed as JBOD
5. Check the check box under the "Select" column
6. Click "Submit", at this point the drive should automatically get assigned to the RAID group
7. Click on the RAID that is critical
8. Click on the "Rebuild" tab, the RAID should start rebuilding